# How to access css/js file for layout of a module in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-modules

I have a module named `social` with the directories like this :

```
frontend
-- modules
    -- social
        -- assets
            -- SocialAsset.php
        -- controllers
        -- views
            -- default
            -- layouts
                -- main.php
        -- web
            -- css
            -- js
            -- img
        Module.php
```

I want my module have an own layout. Because of that, i add file `SocialAsset`, `main.php` for layout, `css`, `js` and `img`. But, unfortunatelly i can't access my `css`/`js`/`img` files.
`SocialAsset` file :

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\social\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class SocialAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $sourcePath = '@app/modules/social/web';
    public $css = [
        'css/social.css',
        'css/toolkit.css'
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/jquery.min.js',
        'js/social.js',
        'js/toolkit.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

in `main.php` i use the `SocialAsset`files like this :

```
use frontend\modules\social\assets\SocialAsset;


SocialAsset::register($this);
```

Could someone to help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only set `sourcePath` in your asset bundle :

> `sourcePath` specifies the root directory that contains the asset
>   files in this bundle. This property should be set if the root
>   directory is not Web accessible. Otherwise, you should set the
>   `basePath` property and `baseUrl`, instead.

This means you should simply remove `$basePath` and `$baseUrl` in your assset bundle, Yii will then *publish* your files.

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html